# How to change my Streamlit app's default storage of image data from my computer to deta.sh database?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, streamlit

I've been working on a machine learning app which predicts the whether the given x-ray image is affected with pneumonia or not. The app is built on VS Code. I had used Streamlit framework for user interface and deta.sh cloud database for storing any useful data.

I had built the machine learning model, created a basic user interface using Streamlit. Also, built the login and signup function for existing or new users. The app is working on my local machine just fine. I also used deta.sh cloud database to store the data of the model (i.e. user ID and password, images uploaded previously etc.) to access it later.

The user ID and password are stored in the deta.sh cloud database, which is alright. However, the x-ray images I am uploading on the web app are stored on my computer. Is there any way I can store those images on deta.sh database?

I have attached the code snippet of the Streamlit app. Please let me know what changes I can do to make those images get stored on deta.sh storage instead of my computer.

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose an image...", type= ["jpg","png","jpeg"])
if uploaded_file is not None:
# st.image (uploaded_file, caption="uploaded Image", use_column_width=True) # idhar se integration ka code...
img = Image.open(uploaded_file).resize((255,255))
st.image (img, use_column_width=False)
save_image_path='./upload_images/' + uploaded_file.name with open(save_image_path, 'wb') as f:
f.write(uploaded_file.getbuffer())
if uploaded_file is not None:
result = processed_img(save_image_path) e_path)
if result == yes:
else:
st.error(result)
st.success(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deta space has a drive. We can use it to store files.

```
"""Put files in deta space drive.

Refs:
    https://deta.space/docs/en/build/reference/sdk/drive
    https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader
"""

from deta import Deta
import streamlit as st

# Connect.
deta = Deta("Your_data_key")

# Create a drive.
ml_drive = deta.Drive("machine_learning_drive")

# Create upload widget.
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose an image file", type=['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
    img_fn = uploaded_file.name
    ml_drive.put(img_fn, data=bytes_data)
```